# Ubuntu 16.04.1 server and mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have not used Linex or mysql for a couple of years but need to get a system running to test an upgrade for a site in a VM before doing the real thing.

I can login as root with no password but can only see the information_schema database. I have tried `ALTER USER : mysql> ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password'`; but it just gives another `> prompt` and the root password does not work.

I have tried creating a new user and giving the user all rights to *.* and it seems to go but it cannot access anything. I have done a fresh install on Ubuntu 16.04.1 and installed LAMP whit the same problem. Any other ideas? I also tried to create another user but do not have CREATE rights.